# && Not working in If() statement

Tags: php, if-statement

For some weird reason this if statement is not finding a match, when the values are clearly equal to the $change_pct_candle values as shown in var_dump below

```
if($change_pct_candle[1] >= 0.38022813688214 && $change_pct_candle[2] >= 1.3487475915221) {}
```

If I try:

```
if($change_pct_candle[1] >= 0.38022813688214) {}
```

It works. If I try:

```
if($change_pct_candle[2] >= 1.3487475915221) {}
```

It works. When I try:

```
if($change_pct_candle[1] >= 0 && $change_pct_candle[2] >= 1) {}
```

It works. When I try:

```
if($change_pct_candle[1] >= 0.38022813688214 && $change_pct_candle[2] >= 1.3487475915221) {}
```

It doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong here?

The var_dump of $change_pct_candle is:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  float(-0.10984848484848)
  [1]=>
  float(0.38022813688214)
  [2]=>
  float(1.3487475915221)
  [3]=>
  float(-0.57471264367815)
  [4]=>
  float(0.19193857965451)
  [5]=>
  float(0.19230769230769)
  [6]=>
  float(0.1926782273603)
}
```

Comment: your unknown `if` is failing you somehow. Plus, arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what is unknown? And if you mean how arrays start at 0, yes, as you see in the var_dump I am using ==  value of [1]

Comment: `If() statement`, where's that? All you included was `&&`.

Comment: I thought it would be assumed that these were in an if() statement @Fred-ii-

Comment: Updated to include if()

Comment: And by not working, you mean??

Comment: @SvenKahn You haven't defined what you mean by "works" or "doesn't work". What are you doing to determine that?

Comment: if(statement) { die(); } - just to see if it matches

Comment: Try an `||` (OR) statement then. Hard to say what you're comparing it against. You only showed the array. Maybe I'm not grasping something though; see if others can pick up on it.

Comment: @Hackerman not finding match is what I mean. I think this is all pretty obvious, I didn't think it had to be completely spelled out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it can't be OR, it must be AND

Comment: Looks to me like a [float precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue: [https://3v4l.org/6amMp](https://3v4l.org/6amMp). What version PHP are you using?

Comment: It wasn't...at first I think that you where trying to perform bitwise operations...also there was not sample input vs expected output behavior, and that was why everyone was asking you about, what `is not working` means :)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes that works for me as well, and works testing on my server. Looking into this.

Comment: @Mike yes it seems to be float problem. When I reduce numbers down to x.xxx it works fine. There might be a bug in the way numbers get stored when adding to array in the method I am adding them, really unsure, looking into it further

Comment: @JonathanKuhn PHP 7.0.11 - your example works, and on my server it works. But when I reduce the float down to x.xx in my actual code, it works, I think there is a bug in how values are getting added to the array

Comment: @SvenKahn In the link I posted above: *"So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available."*. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php.

Comment: @Mike thank you for this, looks like I have to change my code to reduce the float

Comment: Or you could try rounding the numbers to, say, 3-4 decimal places. I'm not sure at what point PHP loses its floating point precision, but I think it should probably be good in those cases.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is "Floating point numbers have limited precision".
Just have a look at this page from php.net and pay close attention to the warning about this concept. That'll explain why , and hopefully what to do.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality.

Comment: This was already mentioned in a comment above.

Comment: Well, probably because that's the key to the solution of your problem

Comment: Yes @Mike figured this out first, so I don't feel great accepting the answer from you. But yes, you are right on it.

Comment: @SvenKahn I can't post an answer because you haven't posted a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think answers almost always should explain what's wrong and also provide working code to fix it.